# RuntimeWarning: coroutine "FUNCTION" was never awaited

Tags: python

so im getting this error and i don't know what im doing wrong , it says that my function was never awaited when it actually was

***CODE***

```
@sclient.on('auth_code_required')
async def auth_code_prompt(is_2fa, mismatch):
    def check(m):
            return m.channel == c
    if is_2fa:
        await c.send("2FA required ! please provide your 2fa code")
        code = await client.wait_for('message',check = check)
        client.login(two_factor_code=code,username =  u.content,password = p.content)
    else:
        await c.send("Email Guard")
        code = await client.wait_for('message',check = check)
        client.login(auth_code=code, username =  u.content,password = p.content)
```

***ERROR***:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'auth_code_prompt' was never awaited
```

Comment: The code that calls `auth_code_prompt` is not using `await`

Comment: your function is a coroutine, however the calling function is missing an await.

Comment: but it's called on an event , i can not await that

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that you never used `await auth_code_prompt(...)` in your code.

Maybe you accidentally called it without using `await`?

Comment: auth_code_prompt is called on an event , how can i await that ?

Comment: You need to add more details. What is "sclient" for example? It might be very well possible that you are using a framework which doesn't support async?

Comment: Uhmm too complicated to explain  , but is it possible to use await in Non-async function ?

Comment: no. `await` uses the async event-loop which is only available in an async function. You can us non-async functions inside an async function. But not the other way around.